# Inkscape export from PDF to EMF with the command line (output is blank)

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to convert a PDF file (of only one page) to EMF. If I do it from the Inkscape GUI with the default options the outcome is perfect.

But if I do it with command line the outcome is a blank page.

I'm using this command:

```
inkscape -f=test.pdf --export-emf=test.emf
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Inkscape is working. I was trying to open the file with paint.exe